# How to show image in the canvas when RFID Card is read?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI for an RFID reader. My aim is to show user's image and name for 2 seconds which were created with `canvas.create_text` and `canvas.create_image` in a canvas which has already have some images(like background image, company logo)

I know that I should save images as reference to objects or save them in a list. But where I could not handle is show a Frame or Canvas that contains user's image and name on top of a canvas. Of course it should show different images and names for different users.

All application is very long so I will try to show my code. This is Tkinter class.

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self, configs, settings, master_root):
        self.configs=configs
        self.settings=settings
        self.root = master_root
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=480, height=800)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.waiting_screen()

    def image_opener(self, filename):
        opened_image = Image.open(CURRENT_DIR + self.configs.Folders.Gui + filename)
        photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(opened_image)
        return photo_image

    '''This creates background picture'''
    def _main_page(self):
        img = self.image_opener("main_page")
        self.canvas.img_main = img
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.canvas.img_main, anchor = NW, state = visibility)

    '''This creates company's logo'''
    def _logo(self, x, y, anc, visibility):
        img = self.image_opener("logo")
        self.canvas.img_logo = img
        self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.canvas.img_logo, anchor = anc, state= visibility)

    '''This shows todays date'''
    def _date_and_day(self, x, y, anc, visibility ):
        today = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(),"dd MMMM", locale = 'en').upper()
        day = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(), "EEEE", locale = 'en').upper()
        self.canvas.create_text(x, y, fill= "white", font = "Corbel 36",   anchor = anc, state= NORMAL, text = today)
        self.canvas.create_text(x, y+55, fill= "white", font = "Corbel 36",   anchor = anc, state= NORMAL, text = day)

    ''This will show user's name, title and photo. Now name, title and photo is static. But will be dynamic.'''
    def _show user_(self,x=240, y=430, anc=CENTER, visibility=NORMAL):
        img = self.image_opener(self.configs.Gui.Images.AccessBackground)
        self.canvas.img_access = img        
        self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.canvas.img_access, anchor = anc, state=visibility)
        #self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image = self.image_user, anchor = anc, state=visibility)
        self.canvas.create_text(x, y+120, fill= "white", font = "Corbel 18",   anchor = anc, state= visibility, text = "EXAMPLE_NAME")
        self.canvas.create_text(x, y+150, fill= "white", font = "Corbel 15",   anchor = anc, state= visibility, text = "EXAMPLE_TITLE")

   def show_gui(self):    
        today = self.settings.Weather.Today
        self._main_page()
        self._logo(x=40 ,y=25, anc=NW, visibility=NORMAL)
        self._date_and_day(x=40 ,y=120, anc=NW, visibility=NORMAL)
        self._user_background(x=240 ,y=430, anc=CENTER, visibility=NORMAL)
```

and here is how I call this class inside main(). There some other things as well in main so I will write just the code about Tkinter. Assume user's info(name, title and image path are being passed to Tkinter class.)

```
def main():
    settings = read_settings()
    configs = get_configs()
    root = Tk()
    gui = GUI(configs, settings, root)   
    gui.show_gui()
    root.mainloop()
```

So what I am really confused what should I do. Should I continue to use canvas or change my code to labels and frames. In documentation I read that labels are also for showing images. It would be very kind If I have any code example for my purpose.

Comment: functions `create_xxx` gives you object ID - `obj_id = canvas.create_image(...)` - which you can use to remove element `canvas.delete(obj_id)` or move it `canvas.move(obj_id)` , etc.

Comment: you can put many images on one canvas, you don't have to create another frame or canvas to put another image on first canvas. But if you need it then you can use `canvas.create_window(..., window=Frame())` to add frame to canvas. And don't use pack/grid/place with this frame.

Comment: to remove element after 2 second you can use `root.after(2000, function_name)` to run function after 2000ms (2s) which will use `canvas.delete(obj_ID)` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, it was very helpful. What about updating an image which has been created with create_image function. How can I do that? @furas

Comment: the same as with widgets `img_id = canvas.create_image(...)` `canvas.itemconfig(img_id, image=new_image)`, `canvas.move(img_id, offset_xm offset_y)`, `canvas.delete(img_id)`. More in documentation: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: my examples on GitHub: [canvas-change-image](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__canvas__/canvas-change-image), [other canvas examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__canvas__), [other tkinter examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter)

Comment: Can I make those gui changes after `root.mainloop()`. I added  my `kill_element()` function which contains `canvas.delete()` function after `root.mainloop()` but it did not worked.

Comment: code after `root.mainloop()` is executed after you close window so canvas doesn't exist at this moment. You have to do in function which you execute when you press button which close window. But if you close window then there is no need to delete images because Python will remove them from memory with all window.

Comment: Problem is I do not have button.. I need to trigger "image appear>wait 2 seconds> image disappear" actions with a trigger from another function

Comment: then put image and in next line of code add `root.after(2000, kill_element)` to run this function after 2000ms (2s)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196620/discussion-between-erondem-and-furas).